# Как отловить событие включения экрана телефона, чтобы снова поднять вэбсокеты?

Tags: javascript, mobile-web

Есть такая проблема, что на странице spa в браузере при выключении экрана (допустим юзер смотрит на страничку в браузере, но нажал кнопку выключения, или просто экран погас из-за неактивности юзера - он просто смотрит, не свайпит, не тапает) ложатся сокеты.

Экран погас, затем юзер включает экран, видит браузер, видит страничку которая и была. Он не тапает, не свайпит - прост осмотрит, например на встроенный чат. Рест-апи при этом будет нормально работать, если он куда-то кликнет, а вот сокеты - лежат.

Юзер включил погасший экран кнопкой, видит страницу с чатом, а чат не обновляется, ничего не происходит - сокеты отрубились в момент выключения экрана.

**Вопрос: на какое событие бы повесить перезапуск сокетов?**
Есть ли какое-то событие, происходящее в браузере в момент включения экрана?
Может фокус, или что-то подобное?

Comment: может быть добавить индикатор соединения и кнопку обновить?

Comment: Для начала укажите используемые модули. Если это `SocketIo`, то в документации есть `autoreconnect` , либо на ивент закрытия соединения вешаете авто подключение.

Comment: Используются нативные вебсокеты, без SocketIo.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API): у меня только оно и заработало.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    (function() {
      const events = [
        "pagehide", "pageshow", "unload", "load", "visibilitychange"
      ];
      events.forEach(e =>
        window.addEventListener(e, () => alert(e), false)
      );
    })(); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```